# jQuery carousel that should be linking but isn't

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery carousel set up on this website http://www.scrummagazine.com/ it holds lots and lots of logos and each logo is supposed to link to an advertisers site, except they don't, the mouse goes in to a hover state and when you click on one of the logos nothing happens? There's a lot going on on this site maybe there's some kind of script conflict? It's probably quite simple but it's been a long day, I'm now baffled. Would be very grateful if someone could take a look, thanks.

Comment: Probably is some script conflict issue. Comment out a script and then try it, and do the same for the rest until you find the culprit then let me know which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Timm, but I found out that it helps to include the following in your functions file

```
            $(function() {
                $('a[rel*=external]').click( function() {
                    window.open(this.href);
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

D'oh!

Comment: Oh ok! Just to let you know the first link (aaacoaches) is missing the rel="external" code, so that link doesn't work but the rest do now! Well done on fixing it :)

Comment: Thanks Timm, I was testting it without the rel="external" but it's back now. Cheers.